# Trying to make autocomplete work in TypeScript for my library

Tags: typescript

SO, I have a function, that takes values of object and return another object that use those values as keys. It looks something like this:

```
function fn(actions) {
  return keys.reduce((acc, m) => {
    const name = actions[m]
    acc[name] = () => { /* some function */}
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

Now, somehow I want to type it so that when I call it

```
res = fn({"something": "go", "something else": "run"})
res. // ...
```

autocomplete would work to suggest that there are indeed 2 methods can be invoked "go" and "run".

So basically I expect res to have type of `{ [key in 'go' | 'run']: Function }`.

Is that possible to achieve with TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the string literal types in the object. You could use `as const` on the object itself, or you can use the trick that TS will preserve the string literal types if the string literal is assigned to a generic type parameter.

With the string literal types you can then create the mapped type you need:

```
function fn<V extends string, T extends Record<keyof T, V>>(actions: T) {
  var keys = Object.keys(actions) as Array<keyof T>
  return keys.reduce((acc, m) => {
    const name = actions[m]
    acc[name] = () => { /* some function */}
    return acc
  }, {} as { [P in T[keyof T]]: () => void })
}

let res = fn({"something": "go", "something else": "run"})
res.go()
res.run();
res.Run()  // err
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=13&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAaogpgDylsAEwGdFioAnGMAcwBpEAVbPAkxAJSwjgsNQDWWAJ5xgTBugB8UgBQBDaPDDEAXEwCUiAN4BYAFCJEAN3kVEQ4aQC8iAPIAjAFbcoAOkvEFShMS3zSAEEKCnlhQRExJikDIwosKBAKJE83eMIQCCxZbwgGAFstaykdWKNEHhUoRDB5fKxEW0VYXwBtfIBdMqNFCFba+o7GxFkiku1EAHoAKjI4euRwHyRpyYBfbsR4xOTEXrK1hm01vdIJ1oAFRGomVssoxg6O9VHGkuM4GEJENY0DDf0BgANgktlgbMgwLJtAAiYjzBIAC2oNBh6hhNDgMIYcIRUGRtGwQOIWDRiBhFHAMN+BnixDcmNGtPBaXAowA3Mz6Rw2VoppNsCEgA)